# math formula behind code

Tags: php, math, resize, thumbnails

Does anyone know the mathematical formula that relates the following strings of code ?

```
 // aspect ratio <
 $src_pos = array(0, (($new_size[1] - $thumb_height) * ($src_size[1] /$new_size[1])) / 2 );
 // aspect ratio >
 $src_pos = array((($new_size[0] - $thumb_width) * ($src_size[0] / $new_size[0])) / 2, 0);
```

They are inside a wider script that creates thumbs from uploaded images:

```
//variables
$src_size = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$thumb_width = 250;
$thumb_height = 200;
$src_aspect = round(($src_size[0] / $src_size[1]), 1);
$thumb_aspect = round(($thumb_width / $thumb_height), 1);

if ($src_aspect < $thumb_aspect){
    //higher
    $new_size = array($thumb_width,($thumb_width / $src_size[0]) * $src_size[1]);
    $src_pos = array(0, (($new_size[1] - $thumb_height) * ($src_size[1] /$new_size[1])) / 2 );
}else if($src_aspect > $thumb_aspect){
    //wider
    $new_size = array(($thumb_width / $src_size[1]) * $src_size[0], $thumb_height);
    $src_pos = array((($new_size[0] - $thumb_width) * ($src_size[0] / $new_size[0])) / 2, 0);
}else{
    //same shape
    $new_size = array($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
    $src_pos = array(0, 0);
}

if ($new_size[0] < 1) $new_size[0] = 1;
if ($new_size[1] < 1) $new_size[1] = 1;


//creation of thumb
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $src, 0, 0, $src_pos[0], $src_pos[1], $new_size[0], $new_size[1], $src_size[0], $src_size[1]);
```

I am studing this script but I cant understand the logic behind the two lines of code I wrote at the beginning of this question, so I'd like to know which mathematical formula they are related to.

Comment: looks like PHP So I added TAG to enable syntax highlight if you have different language change the TAG with language you are using

Comment: O yes sorry, it is PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to look at each aspect ratio `if` part separately you mixed them together which is a bit confusing from start (added the comments to your question).

**I see it like this:**

```
// load image
$src_size = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
// static fixed resolution for the thumb
$thumb_width = 250; 
$thumb_height = 200;
// aspects (if the x or y size is bigger for image and thumb
$src_aspect = round(($src_size[0] / $src_size[1]), 1);
$thumb_aspect = round(($thumb_width / $thumb_height), 1);

// rescale height because the result will not exceeding thumb height in this case
if ($src_aspect < $thumb_aspect){
    $new_size = array
     (
     $thumb_width,                                 // thumb width stays as is
     ($thumb_width / $src_size[0]) * $src_size[1]  // thumb height is rescaled by image aspect
     );
    // this just compute the distance to move the thumb after rescaling so it is still centered
    $src_pos = array(0, (($new_size[1] - $thumb_height) * ($src_size[1] /$new_size[1])) / 2 );
}
// rescale width because the result will not exceeding thumb width in this case
else if($src_aspect > $thumb_aspect){
    $new_size = array
     (
     ($thumb_width / $src_size[1]) * $src_size[0],  // thumb width is rescaled by image aspect
     $thumb_height                                 // thumb height stays as is
     );
    // this just compute the distance to move the thumb after rescaling so it is still centered
    $src_pos = array((($new_size[0] - $thumb_width) * ($src_size[0] / $new_size[0])) / 2, 0);
}else{
    //same shape
    $new_size = array($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
    $src_pos = array(0, 0);
}

if ($new_size[0] < 1) $new_size[0] = 1;
if ($new_size[1] < 1) $new_size[1] = 1;


//creation of thumb
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $src, 0, 0, $src_pos[0], $src_pos[1], $new_size[0], $new_size[1], $src_size[0], $src_size[1]);
```

I hope the comments are enough for you ... but to be sure let us examine:

- `( $thumb_width / $src_size[0]) * $src_size[1]`

I would use this instead (so just integer math can be used)

- `( $thumb_width * $src_size[1] ) / $src_size[0]`

So `$thumb_width` is the thumb nail target maximal resolution and `$src_size[1] / $src_size[0]` is image aspect ratio constant less then `1.0`. When you look at the whole line more closely it is simple linear interpolation without offset (starting point is at `(0,0)`) so the result will be smaller then thumbnail resolution (will fit inside) and still be matching original image aspect ratio.

**Mathematical formula:**

- lets have 2 points `(x0,y0)` and `(x1,y1)` representing endpoints of a line.
- and some arbitrary point `(x,y)` inside/on the line

So if we know one coordinate of a point on line we can compute the other by exploiting triangle similarities like this:

- `x=x0+(y-y0)*(x1-x0)/(y1-y0)`
- `y=y0+(x-x0)*(y1-y0)/(x1-x0)`

This is called linear interpolation. As in your case `(x0,y0)=(0,0)` then the equation became:

- `x=y*x1/y1`
- `y=x*y1/x1`

Which is what your code represents... while `x,y` is `new_size` and `x1,y1` is `src_size`

**Now the position offset**

for example you computed it like this:

- `($new_size[0] - $thumb_width) * ($src_size[0] / $new_size[0])) / 2`
  so the terms are:
- `($new_size[0] - $thumb_width)` is empty space between new and original thumbnail resolution
- `($new_size[0] - $thumb_width)/2` is how much you need to shift resized thumbnail to place it in the middle of original thumbnail resolution
- `($src_size[0] / $new_size[0])` is just scale converting this offset from thumbnail coordinates to image coordinate system

When you put all together you got position which is a bit outside the image (so the missing data is filled with background color) So when copied data from image to thumbnail from this position you got the rescaled thumbnail image centered with empty space around the rescaled axis... (unless I am missing something)

Comment: Thanks spektre, I am studing what u answered.

Comment: if 
    x=y*x1/y1
    y=x*y1/x1

it means that:

y=(($thumb_width * $src_size[1]) / $src_size[0])
x=($thumb_height * $src_size[0]) / $src_size[1])

The frist case returns the samee results of
y=($thumb_width / $src_size[0]) * $src_size[1])

but the second case does'nt not return the same results of
x=($thumb_width / $src_size[1]) * $src_size[0])

Comment: In the equation: 
    x=y*x1/y1
    y=x*y1/x1
Do you mean that x,y are thumb_size and x1,y1 is src_size, right? Or x, y are new_size?

Comment: the link http://www.matteocorona.com/interpolation/li.php show you an example of my first question in the comments. As u can see there is a different result if I apply the formula u suggested to me to the wider image (calculating the new width). 
In the "yellow div thumb" then, I have to set the css' background-image-pos-x negative (with the - sign in front) in order to match the right simulation.

Comment: @MatteoCorona 1. `x=y*x1/y1 y=x*y1/x1` must be the same because `x/y` must be the same as `x1/y1` which is aspect ratio preservation... if it does not match then you got a mistake somewhere (or I got a typo). by `x,y` I mean any point in your case `new_size` and by `x1,y1` the `src_size` (the thumb size is just limit for visualization). 2. I did not use different formulas all are exactly the same as in your code (unless I got a typo) the only suggestion I offer was to first multiply and then divide not the other way around but the formula is the same.

Comment: I understand logic behind this script and for that I want really thank you.
Now I adjusted the script and the new_size equations match.
However there is something strange remaining. It regards the src_pos variable.
In the Wider sequence, I have to cut the  scale converting part "*($src_size[0] / $new_size[0])" in order to achieve the right result:
 $new_size = array(($thumb_height / $src_size[1]) * $src_size[0], $thumb_height);
      $src_pos = array((($new_size[0] - $thumb_width)) / 2, 0);

If I cut the same part in the src_pos of the higher sequence, the result went wrong too.
Why?

Comment: @MatteoCorona not a clue ... without knowing what effect exactly you want to achieve. also it can be related to copy the image data... I am not used to copy non existent parts of image yours (first time I saw this was in your script)`imagecopyresampled` it can be a bug (or that function cant handle such thing) inside that function too. But I do not actively code in PHP so I may be just fishing around real cause ... From math perspective it should work ...